# Why am i getting "NameError: name 'bs4' is not defined" error while trying to import BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, spyder

```
> soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.Text, "xml")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-14-ad3307f493a7>", line 1, in <module>
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.Text, "xml")

**NameError: name 'bs4' is not defined**
```

How can i fix this problem? I'm trying to make an application with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: maybe `import bs4` first?

Comment: in cmd `pip install beautifulsoup4` and try `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` then `soup=BeautifulSoup(r.Text, "xml")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import bs4 first (assuming you have installed bs4), i.e.

```
> import bs4
> soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.Text, "xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this

import bs4

soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.Text, "xml")

Comment: How's that different than the other answer?